# Attempt at centring drawer items makes them have zero text

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

https://snack.expo.dev/5spvLQAsL

In the above snack, I have made a simple edit on line 29 from the default:

```
drawerStyle: {
  flex:1,
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center"
},
```

Yet, this somehow causes the text to disappear. How can I centre a list of drawer items without having their label text seemingly disappear?